# Exercise 8.7 on Haim Brezis' book

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am doing the exercises about Sobolev spaces on the book of Haim Brezis, and I am geting stuck with this,

Let $I=(0,1)$, given a function $u$ defined  on $I$,

$$\bar{u}(x)=\begin{cases}
u(x), & x \in I \\
0, & x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus I \end{cases}$$
Assume that $u\in L^p(I)$ with $1\leq p <\infty$, such that $\bar{u}\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$, prove that $u \in W^{1,p}_0(I)$

Since $\bar{u}$ is a continous function, so I am trying to use a Cutt-Off technic to get a sequence with a compac support converging to $u$ but I couldn't apply this idea, Any hint or intermediate question please?

Comment: why are you trying to do that?

Comment: @Masacroso because it is easy to show that $u \in W^{1,p}(I)$ so it is sufficient to find a sequence of function in $C^1_c(I)$ that converge to $u$, are there any problem in this reasoning? thank you in advance

Comment: "Let ... given...assume...such that ..." OK, and what's the question?

Comment: @CalvinKhor thank you, it is fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof: $u \in W_0^{1,p}(0,1)$

- For all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,1)$ (hence its $0$-extension $\tilde \varphi$ is in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$) we have
  $$ -\int_0^1 u(x) \partial_x \varphi(x) \text{ d}x = - \int_\mathbb{R} \tilde u(x) \partial_x \tilde \varphi(x) \text{ d}x = \int_\mathbb{R} \partial_x \tilde u(x) \tilde \varphi(x) \text{ d}x=\int_0^1 v(x) \varphi(x) \text{ d}x$$
  where $v(x):=\begin{cases} \partial_x \tilde u(x), &\text{for } x \in (0,1) \\ 0, &\text{else} \end{cases}$ is the weak derivative of $u$. Showing that $v \in L^p(0,1)$ is straight forward.
- Since $u \in W^{1,p}(0,1)\subset C([0,1])$, it remains to show $u(0)=u(1)=0$. Also $\tilde u \in C(\mathbb{R})$, hence $u(x) \to 0$ for $x \to 0$ and $u(y) \to 0$ for $y \to 1$. Now use the continuity of $u$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I am sorry for the delay reply, but could you please tell me how did you get $\tilde u \in C(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @F.Marko $\tilde u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}) \subset C(\mathbb{R})$ by the Sobolev embedding, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality

Comment: @Kovalevskaya But $W^{1,p}(0,1) \subset  C([0,1]) $ is true when $ p >n$. Here we have $n=1$ and $p \geq 1$. So we cannot say $\bar u \in C(\mathbb{R})$ if $p =1 $.

Comment: @notpron $W^{1,1}(0,1)$ is embedded in $C([0,1])$ in 1D. This should be proved in every functional analysis/PDE book, e.g., see p.68 in "Linear Functional Analysis" by H.W. Alt.

Comment: @Kovalevskaya Haven't heard of it, thanks!